# Stoping a Swing Timer within the actionPerformed Method?

Tags: java, swing, timer

How would I stop a Swing timer within it's actionPerformed method?
I am able to start and stop the timer outside the actionPerformed method but not with in the method how would I accomplish this?

```
final int i =0;
    final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        int i = 0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i == 100) {
                timer.stop();
            }


        }    
    });
    timer.start();
```

Comment: 10milisecond is very short period, overloading SW & HW latency, use >33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping swing timers from within the action method works fine. I think the issue with your code is, that it doesn't even compile because you are accessing the `timer` variable before it is assigned.

Split the assignment into two parts like below and it'll compile and work fine.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(10, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the timer as a class member. Also you probably want to declare `int i` as a class member also, since creating a new one inside the timer makes no sense, if you're trying to increment it each repeat. See my code corrections

```
Timer timer = null;
int i = 0;
public Constructor() {

    timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i == 100) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }    
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Timer from the ActionEvent:

```
Timer timer = (Timer)evt.getSource();
```